# Formular for Gauß-Curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

can someone pls help me and tell me where this formular comes from:

[image]

I know that you can derivate the curvature as the qoutient from the second and first fundamental form, does this formular comes from the theorema egregium?

Comment: No, it presumably comes from the Gauss equation(s).

Comment: Thanks, do you have a source where I can see the details?

Comment: I’ve actually never seen this particular formula except in the case $F=0$, but you can find the Gauss equation in any standard text. See, for example, pp. 58-60 of my text, which is freely linked in my profile.

Comment: Where did you find this formula?

Comment: It looks related to (maybe a special case?) of proposition 6.2.16 on page 285 or https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/analmv.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjB55ets7v7AhUEVTUKHbuGCCkQFnoECBMQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0-AVr1GDX5Emh-g_kgANkW

Comment: @Mason This is indeed the well-known formula in the case $F=0$ to which I referred.

Comment: To echo @Deane's question, I would need to see the material preceding this formula. Although it is close to working out correctly, it does not, as there are serious sign issues, even if I restrict to the case $F=0$.

Comment: I refer to this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748974/gaussian-curvature-k-of-of-orthogonal-parametrization-x    its also an exercise in Carmo: Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces